# Why am I only getting 100 Mbps from my home network?

Tags: dd-wrt, gigabit-ethernet

I have an external hard drive (a [WD 2TB My Book Live](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=280)) connected to a router (a [D-Link DIR-615](http://support.dlink.ca/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-615) running [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.ca/site/index)) via ethernet cable. I also have a desktop with a "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" connected to the same router via an ethernet cable.

Whenever I transfer files across the network, speeds are limited to about 11 MB/s. Considering that both the external hard drive and desktop are capable of gigabit speeds, I would have expected a slightly faster transfer rate.

According to Windows 8.1, the adapter on the desktop machine is connected at 100.0 Mbps:

[image]

I checked the Device Manager, and "Speed & Duplex" for the adapter is set to "Auto Negotiation". So this is obviously a problem with the router.

I used `telnet` to connect to the router and check the speed of `eth0`:

```
# cat /sys/devices/platform/ag71xx.0/net/eth0/speed
100
```

Why is the router operating at a slow speed? Is there anything I can do to make it faster?

Comment: Could be the cable - have you tried another one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because DIR-615 is a non-gigabit capable router. It has 4 x 10/100 ports, and 1 x 10/100 WAN port.

Even if your PC, and your NAS can support Gigabit, the weakest link speed will be used.

Check D-Link DIR615 Spec [here](http://files.dlink.com.au/Products/DIR-615/Datasheet/DIR-615_datasheet_04.pdf).

The only way to make it faster, is to get a new router that support gigabit. Or maybe direct-connect your PC to your NAS via ethernet.

Comment: Blah, can't believe I missed that. Nice catch

Comment: Hmmm... I better keep my eyes out for an upgrade.